# Threshold image to show ip address using python

Tags: python

I have an image that has ip address above the word `United States`. I am trying to make it clearer by thresholing it, but it didn't work as expected. I need to make the ip clearer and if possible to be able to extract it
This is my try

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Sample.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)

th, threshed1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
th, threshed2 = cv2.threshold(b, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imwrite('Output.png', threshed1)
```

Here's snapshot as sample file
[image]

Comment: In what way was the output different than expected? One thing I noticed is that you are combining the flags with '|'. That is great for ints but [this example](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) from the documentation shows using the plus sign. There must be some overloading going on. I couldn't find an explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I expected the IP address part to be clearer like the text below it.

Comment: For THRESH_OTSU you should use a threshold of 0. The link I provided before shows an example like that. You might also try the adaptive thresholding in that example.